# How install XFCE and remove gnome on Ubuntu 20.0.4 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, thunar

Was running xUbuntu 18.0.4 LTS and upgraded (re-install via DVD) to Ubuntu 20.0.4.  I'd like to get back to the XFCE Desktop as it find gnome unusable for my application.  In particular I have a lot of problems with nautilus and would like to use Thunar.

I attempted to install it following an article on Linuxconfig.org which gave the following procedure:

sudo apt install tasksel
sudo tasksel install xubuntu-desktop

This may or may not have installed xfce but it mentions there is then some step to select the desktop.  Unfortunately I can find no selector anywhere nor do I wish to have go thru the selection process every time I reboot.

Is there any way I can install the XFCE making my system xUbuntu and remove gnome or as much of gnome as is possible?  Of course this pertains to Focal Fossa: ie Ubuntu 20.0.4.  If I have to I can do a new install presuming I can find a xUbuntu 20.0.4 release.

Comment: Did you consider just downloading Thunar and [setting it as your default file manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030712/1103141)?

Comment: Yes, however from reading this is not possible under Unity.  Nautilus handles both icons and files and supposedly, from everything I read it doesn't work.  Also I executed the install of the xfce desktop per the tasksel above.  Yet Nautilus remains my file manager.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it through `apt`:

```
sudo apt install xubuntu.
```

or (not the same)

```
sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop^
```

then remove unity:

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: So this does a complete installation of xUbuntu 20.0.4?  How is the desktop only different?  Do i need the ^?   I did look at common responses online before posting but was hoping for more detail.

Comment: @NicholasBourbaki `sudo apt install xubuntu.` will install all `xubuntu*` (package starting with `xubuntu` including `xubuntu-desktop`). you can simulate the installation `sudo apt -s install xubuntu.`